# Select a div with tab

Tags: jquery, button, hover, href

I have this close buttons on jQuery UI dialogs that use . This is annoying because when the user hovers above it, the browser will display a useless link at the bottom of the page (which i really cant have there because I use a status-bar at the bottom).

When I remove the attribute href the problem is solved, but now when I tab over the elements of my dialog, the buttons that have no href will be skipped.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit:
HTML:

```
<html><head>...(script includes)</head><body>
<div id="someDialog">
</body></html>
```

Js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#someDialog").dialog();
 )};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmarcon/jTGCF/1/
Open the dialog and hover over the close "x"

Comment: Please show your HTML + CSS for this element,

Comment: please provide html, what you currently have is not helpful.  Better yet, provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really can't have status bar showing anything you need to remove the anchor tags completely and use javascript for navigation instead on selected elements (as you already do!).

Then use `tabindex` to control which order and elements tab presses go.

Updated your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jTGCF/201/
(try to tab between the two buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your status bar. Here is jus one example: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Jun/13/A-jQuery-Client-Status-Bar

Looks nicer than what most browsers show and is much more visible to users. Not sure about other users but the only time I ever look at the built in status bar is when I'm debugging my own apps.